# Rename Music Files with Missing File Extensions

Tags: filesystem, music

I've been trying out a few different music players recently and noticed that some (a lot) of my music would be missing from the library. It turns out that at some point, a plethora of my music files lost their .mp3/.ogg/.flac file extensions. I'm honestly not sure how this happened, but I'm confident it was something I did mistakenly (or maybe I thought it wouldn't matter since file extensions are mostly cosmetic anyway).

So I need to get these file extensions back. I've looked into pyrenamer, but I can't figure out how to match it to files without an extension and then tell it to add the *correct* file extension depending on the actual type of the file.

I've also looked at EasyTag. However, it also recognizes music files based entirely on their file extensions. So the music I want to fix doesn't even show up. Brilliant.

Any thoughts on how to do this? I certainly don't mind some command line, I'm just not sure which tools would be best and I also suck at regex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a bash script that renames the files passed to it based on their guessed format. It calls [`file`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man1/file.1.html) to figure out the format by looking at characteristic patterns in the first few bytes. `file -i` prints lines like `/path/to/file: type/subtype` where `type/subtype` is a [MIME type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type). The script then associates extensions to known types and renames the file to have the extension. Files that already have the extension are left alone. Files that have an unrecognized type are left alone. The script will prompt before overwriting a target file.

```
#!/bin/bash
# usage:
# fixmime ./{**/,}*
file --mime-type "$@" |
while read -r line; do
  file=${line%:*}
  type=${line##* }
  case $type in

    #Audio
    audio/x-flac) ext=flac;;
    audio/mpeg) ext=mp3;;
    application/ogg) ext=ogg;;

    #Video
    video/mp4) ext=mp4;;
    video/x-flv) ext=flv;;
    application/octet-stream) ext=webm;;
    application/x-shockwave-flash) ext=swf;;

    #Images
    image/png) ext=png;;
    image/jpeg) ext=jpg;;
    image/gif) ext=gif;;
    image/x-ico) ext=ico;;

    #Text
    text/plain) ext=md;; #markup your notes, even when they are plain
    text/html) ext=html;;
    text/x-pascal) ext=py;;
    text/x-c++) ext=js;; #conflicts with .cpp, so use prefered
    text/x-c) ext=scss;; #usualy it is .c
    text/x-shellscript) ext=sh;;
    application/pdf) ext=pdf;;

    #Fonts
    application/x-font-ttf) ext=ttf;;
    application/vnd.ms-opentype) ext=otf;;

    #Archive
    application/x-gzip) ext=tar.gz;;
    application/x-bzip2) ext=tar.bz;;

    *) continue;;
  esac
  [[ $file = *.$ext ]] || mv -i -- "$file" "$file.$ext"
done
```

Save the script as `~/bin/rename-based-on-content-type` (or whatever you like) and make it executable (`chmod +x ~/bin/rename-based-on-content-type`). Pass the names of the files you want to rename to the script on the command line. If you have a directory tree `/path/to/music/directory` that you want to traverse recursively, invoke the script as

```
~/bin/rename-based-on-content-type /path/to/music/directory/{**/,}*
```

Comment: That worked brilliantly. As far as I can tell anyway. I also learned a bit more about bash scripting :) Thanks!

Comment: for some reason this didn't work on all the song, but I was able to quickly pick up the (very) few that it didn't catch using lltag

Answer (score 2):

This bash script could do the trick:

```
#! /bin/bash

find ~/Music -type f | (while read path; do
    case `file -i "$path"` in
        *audio/mp3*|*audio/mpeg*) ext='.mp3' ;;
        *application/ogg*) ext='.ogg' ;;
        *flac*) ext='.flac' ;;
        *) continue;; # ignore unknown files
    esac

    newname="$(dirname "$path")/$(basename "$path" "$ext").$ext"
    if [ "$path" != "$newname" ]; then
        mv -v "$path" "$newname"
    fi
done)
```

The script uses `file -i` to read the MIME type of a file; I have no
FLAC files here, so you might want to check what the MIME type for
FLAC is by running `file -i a_file.flac` (and possibly adjusting the script source).

You can add an option `-i` to `mv` if you want to be asked
confirmation before any file rename.

It might be a good idea to replace `mv -v` by `echo mv -v` and doing a
test run *before* trying the actual renames -- the `echo mv` will
print out the `mv` commands that would be executed by the script.

Comment: A lot of my mp3 files I ran `file -i` on return `audio/mpeg` instead of `audio/mp3`, maybe you could add that to your script?

Comment: @DoR, just add *audio/mpeg*) ext='.mp3' ;; in the first case section