# What command line to reliably traverse several directory levels

Tags: filesystem

I have the same problem as was asked in question 
[Rename Music Files with Missing File Extensions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7321/rename-music-files-with-missing-file-extensions/7327#7327)
and I found the script provided by @Gilles very educational, but unfortunately it didn't work the way I expected. What I was looking for was a script that would add a file extension to all music files without extension in all subdirectories, at all levels, below "/path/to/music/directory/". The suggested command line parameter

```
/path/to/music/directory/{**/,}*
```

makes the script go through all the files in the subdirectories one level below "/path/to/music/directory/" 
but not at levels below that. 
What command line parameter should I use to traverse all files at all levels below "directory/" ?

Would also appreciate a pointer to documentation for the

```
{**/,}*
```

part.

BTW, For those interested in the original answer. I found that the script works better after I changed the line

```
file -i "$@" |
```

to

```
file --mime-type "$@" |
```

(If I had had the privilege level I would have given this as a comment in the original answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have only to activate the bash `globstar` option, because it is not active by default in *Ubuntu*, as explained in the following.

The expression `/path/to/music/directory/{**/,}*` contain two expansion constructs: has a brace expansion and next a pathname expansion.

#### Brace expansion

Brace expansion is best explained with an example:

```
$ printf '%s\n' before-{a,bb,1,22}-after
before-a-after
before-bb-after
before-1-after
before-22-after
```

(I've used, here and in the following, the command `printf '%s\n' item1 item2 etc..` that is like `echo` but prints each element on a new line)

You see that each comma separated element in braces results in an expanded element.

The original example, containing in braces the elements `**/` and an empty element, expands to

```
$ printf '%s\n' /path/to/music/directory/{**/,}*
/path/to/music/directory/**/*
/path/to/music/directory/*
```

#### Globstar

Turn now to the bash glob `**`, that is mentioned two times in the [bash manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/bash.1.html), both in relation to the shell option `globstar`, and the meaning is as follow:

> the pattern ** used in a pathname expansion context will match a files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.

This shell option is not *active* by default in Ubuntu:

```
$ shopt globstar
globstar        off
```

You can activate it with

```
shopt -s globstar
```

(use `shopt -u globstar` to deactivate it).

If we have the following directory structure:

```
$ find first/ | sort
first/
first/aaa
first/second
first/second/bbb01
first/second/bbb02
first/second/third
first/second/third/ccc1
first/second/third/ccc2
first/second/third/ccc3
```

we could have the following expansions:

```
$ printf '%s\n' first/**/a*
first/aaa

$ printf '%s\n' first/**/b*
first/second/bbb01
first/second/bbb02

$ printf '%s\n' first/**/c*
first/second/third/ccc1
first/second/third/ccc2
first/second/third/ccc3
```

so you can see that `**` is able to expand to more than a pathname element.

Comment: Your assumption was right on. Enabling globstar made it work the way I wanted. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this

```
#! /bin/bash

[[ -d "$1" ]] || { echo "$1 not a directory, exiting..."; exit 1; }

find "$1" -type f | while read F; do
  # do what you want with the "$F"
done

exit 0
```

and then invoke the script via `./my_script <directory>`