# How to wildcard directories and all files in them

Tags: directory

Lets say I wanted to wildcard directories and then wildcard all files in those directories.

How would I do so?

I know * is to wildcard all files, but I don't know how to wildcard directories.

For example `pdf2djvu -o /dir/[wildcard dirs]/[wildcards.djvu] /dir/[wildcard dirs]/[wildcards.pdf]`

On a secondary note can such a wildcard be affected if the location had a space where normally typing with "" for spaces it would be better to use \ - this time?

I tried what I posted above using the standard * for the wildcard dirs and wildcard files like `/dir[entire dir had no spaces]/*/*.djvu` but got the following error

`I/O error (basic_ios::clear)`

Comment: I should enable `globstar` if you are using Bash: have a look at [what-command-line-to-reliably-traverse-several-directory-levels](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55255/what-command-line-to-reliably-traverse-several-directory-levels).

Comment: ehh that's a bit confusing I enabled globstar then check if it's enabled but * or {**/,} do not work –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible workaround is to use somethig like:

```
find . -iname *.pdf | xargs -I% pdf2djvu -o % %.djvu
```

This would find all pdf files starting in the current directory (recursive) and run the pdf2djvu command to produce file.pdf.djvu files.

Comment: I get the following error message xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option. I should also mention these files have spaces in them

Comment: With `find`'s `-exec` option and a subshell you can use [Parameter Expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal) and save the pipe: `find . -iname "*.pdf" -exec bash -c 'pdf2djvu -o "$0" "${0%.*}".djvu' {} \;`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is there's no good way to keep the two wildcard expansions in sync and iterate over them, like you're wanting to do.  Since you only want to do this on one file at a time, it would be easier to just use find.  If you want to recursively do this, I'd do `find . -iname '*.pdf' -exec pdf3djvu -o '{}'.djvu '{}' \;`  If you have only certain directories you want to do this in, come up with shell wildcard which expands to those directories, and use that as the argument to find instead of `.`.  For example, if you have several directories which end with "djvus" (like "pie_djvus" and "flag_djvus"):

```
find ./*djvus/ -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.pdf' -exec pdf3djvu -o '{}'.djvu '{}' \;
```

Using the `/` after the glob ensures that the glob will only match directories, and specifying the maxdepth of 1 ensures that the find won't go more than one level deep in the directories specified (which is the top level)

In both cases, you're going to end up with things like "file.pdf.djvu", which may or may not be annoying to you.  So there will be a second post-processing step necessary if you used find.  Here's one way to do it if you're using a recent bash as your shell (some shells will split filenames up on spaces, which will break this - but current bash does not).

```
for F in *.pdf.djvu; do mv -v "$F" "${F%.pdf.djvu}.djvu"; done
```